# Is re-training required on a model pruned using TFMOT?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to prune a pre-trained model using TFMOT (Tensorflow model Optimization ToolKit). Is it necessary to re-train the pruned model to get a reduced gzip size ?
Without re-training, the model gzip size does not reduce

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to train the model to apply pruning.

Pruning slowly reduces some weights to zero during the training process. This gradual process is necessary to maintain a good accuracy, it can be fine tuned with a specific [pruning schedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras/PruningSchedule).
For best results, pruning should be applied to an already trained model.

The Tensorflow team is currently investigating how to apply pruning in a single shot, without training. The objective being not to produce a useful model, but measure the size and performance benefits of pruning without re-training.
https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/issues/621